# Relativistic momentum of an electron

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, photons, kinematics, conservation-laws

Suppose we have some interaction between a photon and an (initially) stationary electron, and we wished to find the final momentum of the electron. Should we solve this using conservation of momentum, using the relationship
$$\mathbf{p}_{\text{photon-initial}}=\mathbf{p}_{\text{photon-final}}+\mathbf{p}_{\text{electron-final}}$$
or by conservation of energy, using the relationship
\begin{align}
E_{\text{photon-initial}}+E_{\text{electron-initial}}=E_{\text{photon-final}}+E_{\text{electron-final}}\\
\Longrightarrow m_ec^2-\Delta E_{\text{photon}}=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_e^2c^4},
\end{align}
and then solve for momentum?

I do get different answers for specific problems regarding photon and stationary electron interactions, and I am wondering if it is a matter of my calculations being off, or some other fundamental error.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/photel.html

Answer (score -1):

You should remember that photons don't have any mass, so relation is $E=p/c$ for photons.
Moreover, you have to count electrons mass when you apply energy equations.
Electron mass will vanish, but it's important to take account of it.
I mean, before the square root, you don't have the electron mass, you have the kinetic energy.